# Convenient way to load (and if needed install) a package in R

Tags: r

A user can work on many PCs. A good code runs no matter what PC it is running on. Assuming one does not want to rely on preference and option files, what is the best way to make sure a package is loaded (and installed if needed).

`library` command is cool, but the `require` command is much better. But even `require` is not getting the job done.

Triggering re-install that is not needed (eg, in R studio) causes an interesting prompt to restart the R session - and this is why unnecessary installs are best avoided.

One possible trick A is to do this (not to type the package name too often)

```
doInstall <- T;toInstall <- c("downloader");
if(doInstall) install.packages(toInstall);
lapply(toInstall, library, character.only = T)
```

or a worse trick B would be

```
if (!require(downloader)) {install.packages("downloader"); require(downloader)}
```

Is there a "2015 way" of doing it with one command - something like

```
justdoitall(c("downloader","dplyr"))
```

Comment: I don't know why you don't like "trick B". The whole issue goes away if you put your code into a package.

Comment: Agree with @Roland. You may also have a look the at `installr::require2`: "`require2` load add-on packages by passing it to `require`. However, if the package is not available on the system, it will first install it (through `install.packages`), and only then try to load it again.". The function adds some more functionality (needed or not).

Comment: There is also the `p_load` function from the [pacman package](https://github.com/trinker/pacman) which does this.  The main issue with using external packages for this is that you need to remember to install/load the package before using the functions which allow you to install and load a package in one go.  If you have them installed you can load them in your .Rprofile but you can't assume everybody will have done that. (Disclosure: I am one of the authors of pacman)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is an example of installing package zipcode using the **pacman** approach.

```
if (!require("pacman")) install.packages("pacman")
pacman::p_load(zipcode)
```

Answer (score 1):

> Assuming one does not want to rely on preference and option files

That rules out putting anything in .Rprofile or using external packages so we're stuck with base R to solve your problem.  If that's the case then the answer is that you can't do this much better than what you have written in your question (I prefer B to A)

If you're willing to bend a little bit and require the user to load a package first (which could be done on startup by using .Rprofile) there are a few options that do exactly what you want.

`installr::require2` and `pacman::p_load` do what you ask.  Disclosure: I am a an author/maintainer of **pacman**.  I agree with your sentiment that we shouldn't rely on options or external files though especially if we plan on sharing the code.  I use **pacman** pretty much every day (it has much more use than just installing/loading packages) but for the most part these types of functions should be treated as useful for interactive use but if you want portable, shareable code without worries about whether packages will be available you will have to resort to something along the lines of what you have in your question.

Comment: very nice package. link for other readers (overview of functions (not PDF) http://trinker.github.io/pacman_dev/vignettes/pacman_functions_quick_reference.html

Comment: @user56 Thanks.  We actually are planning on releasing to CRAN (finally) on Valentines Day.  That should make the installation of pacman easier for most users.